# Linear algebra (row picture and column picture).

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, plane-geometry

I am reading Gilbert strang book of linear algebra. In the book, there is a statement which says "If the $n$ planes have no point in common, or infinitely many points, then the $n$ columns lie in same plane".

Can someone please help me understand the above statement?

Comment: I think it's talking about linearly independent columns.

Comment: Your quote is partial. What are the "n planes"? Are the "n columns" the columns of a given n by n matrix?

Comment: @GuySa, Yes. This is not my quote. It's directly from strangs book.